# Bootstrap popup modal close early when submit?

Tags: php, html

Good day,
 I have a problem regarding on my codes in bootstrap popup modal, it close early when i click submit button/(print)button. would you try to show me the correct way of calling the popup modal?
 Please see my codes below. Thanks for the Help :)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head> 
<!-- Top content -->
<div class="top-content">

  <div class="inner-bg">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 text">
          <h1><strong>IT Request </strong> Form</h1>
          <div class="description">

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 form-box">

          <div class="form-bottom">
            <form role="form" action="#myModal" method="post" class="login-form">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="sr-only">requestor</label>
                <input type="text" name="itrf_requestor" placeholder="Requested By..." class="form-username form-control" id="itrf_requestor">
              </div>

              <button type="submit" class="btn" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Print</button>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

</div>


<!-- Javascript -->
<script src="assets/js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/jquery.backstretch.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/scripts.js"></script>

<!--[if lt IE 10]>
            <script src="assets/js/placeholder.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->

</body>

</html>

<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">



        <form method="POST" action="form.php">
          <input type="text" name="form" value="ITREQUESTFORM-">
          <input type="text" name="itrf_requestor" value="">
          <p>
            <input type="submit" alt="SUBMIT" name="Submit" value="PRINT" class="submit-text" />
        </form>
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have described the modal button type as "Submit" whereas it should be "Button"

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/jquery.backstretch.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/scripts.js"></script>
  <!--[if lt IE 10]>
            <script src="assets/js/placeholder.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
</head>
<!-- Top content -->
<div class="top-content">
  <div class="inner-bg">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 text">
          <h1><strong>IT Request </strong> Form</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 form-box">
          <div class="form-bottom">
            <form role="form" method="post" class="login-form">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="sr-only">requestor</label>
                <input type="text" name="itrf_requestor" placeholder="Requested By..." class="form-username form-control" id="itrf_requestor">
              </div>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Print</button>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
              <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              <form method="POST" action="form.php">
                <input type="text" name="form" value="ITREQUESTFORM-">
                <input type="text" name="itrf_requestor" value="">
                <p>
                  <input type="submit" alt="SUBMIT" name="Submit" value="PRINT" class="submit-text" />
                </p>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</html>
```